# locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation not getting called for Significant Location Changes Monitoring

Tags: iphone, location, monitoring, cllocationmanager

I implemented background location tracking using standard location services, and it works fine. However, since this implementation uses a lot of power, I decided to switch to significant location changes monitoring. Basically, I just changed all the calls to `startUpdatingLocation` to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and reused the CLLocationManagerDelegate methods I have implemented before.

The problem is that after switching to significant location changes monitoring, the delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` only gets called once when I start monitoring, and is never called again afterwards. I have moved around the phone for a couple of kilometers, and tried riding a train with it, but still the method never gets called. Am I missing something here? Are there settings I need to enable or special code I need to write in order for this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significant location change requires cell phone towers in order to operate. If you don't have cell phone reception you will not get any results. You can also call CLLocationManager's significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable method to see if it is available.

Comment: You're right, it seems that the problem is caused by low cellphone signal.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  First, the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key is only required to let "iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run."  Second, the "location" key in UIBackgroundModes is only needed when the app "requires the use of the standard location services (as opposed to the significant change location service)".  Details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html